# Main class not found in project when run - Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a beginner and teaching myself Java from scratch. In my project I have two files, one named root and one that I am working on called PlanetWeight. When I run my file, it runs the Root file but not the file I am working on and instead displays the error:

" PlanetWeight class was not found in Java24 project." and gives me an option to select Root as my main class.

I tried to change it in properties but it didnt work. I would appreciate some guidance if that's ok?

My code:

```
class PlanetWeight{
    public static void main (string[] args){
        System.out.print("your weight on earth is ");
        double weight = 205;
        System.out.println(weight);

        System.out.print("your weight on Mercury is ");
        double mercury = weight * .378;
        System.out.println(mercury);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also if I press shift +F6 it gives me the error that class PlanetWeight does not have a main method

Comment: Does your code compile without errors? `string` should be written with a capital S: `String`.

Comment: Thank you! Argh and I just read about how important Capitalization is!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main (string[] args){
```

should be changed to

```
public static void main (String[] args){
```

In your method declaration you are having a simple s for string. It should be `String`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line.
public static void main (string[] args)

string must start with a capital S.

```
class PlanetWeight{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.print("your weight on earth is ");
        double weight = 205;
        System.out.println(weight);

        System.out.print("your weight on Mercury is ");
        double mercury = weight * .378;
        System.out.println(mercury);
    }
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

The "s' in string must be uppercase so it will look like this:

```
public static void main (String args[]){
}
```